# How to include ClassVars in dataclass asdict() output?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have dataclasses with static fields on them like so:

```py
from typing import ClassVar
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class X:
  static_field: ClassVar[str] = "static_value"
  normal_field: str

@dataclass
class Y:
  x: X

y = Y(x=X(normal_field="normal_value"))
asdict(y) # yields {'x': {'normal_field': 'normal_value'}}
```

How can I make `static_field` part of the output? The field `static_field` should *never* be set when instantiating the class.

Comment: _Why_ do you want them included in the returned dictionary?

Comment: I am creating some dataclasses which are used to serialize/deserialize some json data. In order to populate the proper dataclass, sometimes I need a `"type": "enum"` or `"type": "struct"` field on an object. Essentially, there are identifying fields that are coupled to dataclasses that should not be changed

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses an undocumented feature, the `__dataclass_fields__` attribute, but it works at least in Python 3.9:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Any, ClassVar

def asdict_with_classvars(x) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    '''Does not recurse (see dataclasses._asdict_inner() for how to do that
    right), and fails if x lacks a class variable declared in x's class
    definition.'''
    return dict(
        (name, getattr(x, name))
            for name in x.__dataclass_fields__
    )

@dataclass
class Blah:
    x: int
    y: ClassVar[str] = 'the classvar'

print(asdict_with_classvars(Blah(22)))
```

Output:

```
{'x': 22, 'y': 'the classvar'}
```

If the ClassVar is declared in an abstract class and not defined, it's possible for an instance to be created that doesn't have a value for the ClassVar. In that case, the call to `getattr()` will raise an `AttributeError`. But it's not too hard to handle that and otherwise tailor this to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables):

> If a field is a `ClassVar`, it is excluded from consideration as a field and is ignored by the dataclass mechanisms. Such `ClassVar` pseudo-fields are not returned by the module-level `fields()` function.

So, I don't think that this is possible. You may need to rethink that part of the design.